# Calculus about solving equation with exp.

Tags: calculus

> Prove that the equation $e^x − x − 1 = 0$ has one and only solution. Find that solution.

Hello there! I got this problem on my test last month and I could not solve it at the time. However, I would like to know how the problem could be solved. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: $y = x + 1$ is the tangent line of $y = e^x$ at $x = 0$. So $x = 0$ is the only solution. Not sure how they wanted you to prove that, or what methods you know.

Comment: thanks, mate. Well i can use everything thats is written in Spivak!

Comment: @Kaynex I am not sure that follows. The tangent line can intersect the function at a different point

Comment: One **real** solution. There ought to be infinitely many complex solutions, explicility given by Lambert W. (existence can be shown by Rouche or Picard theorems I'd presume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f(x)=\mathrm e^x-x-1$.  Then $f'(x)=\mathrm e^x-1<0$ if $x<0$, $>0$ if $x>0$, i.e. $f(x)$  decreases to $f(0)=0$ on $\;(-\infty,0]$, then increases from $0$ on $\;[0,+\infty)$, so the sole root of $f(x)=0$ is $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection $x=0, y=1 $ is a solution.

The derivative of $ e^x$ at $x=0$ is $1$. The derivative of $ x+1$ at $x=0$ is also $1$.

So the straight line has tangential contact, a double or coincident soluton.

Repeated points $ (0,1),(0,1)$ are the required double contact points.